# CSS image not showing Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, templates

I've been trying to add an image to Wordpress template, when I add a  tag it auto adds display: none; to it when it appears on the site. So I decided to add it as a css image with div.

I've added this to the CSS:

```
.myad a{
    background-image: url(http://www.henstagweekends.co.uk/images/advert.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 248px;
    width: 189px;
    z-index: 100000;
}
```

I've added this to the footer.php just before the  tag:

```
<div class="myad">
<a href="/jobs-with-epic-events"></a>
</div>
```

I've added a temporary bg colour to show where it is. Look at the very bottom of the page.
http://www.henstagweekends.co.uk/

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Is there a problem with the ad that's currently showing? I see it fine.

Answer (score 0):

`url('URL')` refers to path where images are located. Try download the image to your folder and reference it: `background-image: url('<path>/advert.png')`

Comment: Don't forget to get image dynamically using, `<?php get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>`